# Unsure whether function breaks backpropagation

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I have been tinkering around a lot with tensorflow in the past few days however I am quite unsure whether a function I wrote would break the backpropagation in a Neural network. I thought I'd ask here before I try to integrate this function in a NN. So the basic setup is I want to add two matricies with

```
op = tf.add(tfObject, tfImageBackground)
```

where `tfImageBackground` is some constant image. (i.e. an RGBA image of size 800, 800 with R = G = B = A = 0) and the `tfObject` is again a matrix with the same dimenstion however we get that with the function I am unsure about

```
def getObject(vector):
    objectId = vector[0]
    x = vector[1]
    y = vector[2]
    xEnd = baseImageSize-(x+objectSize)
    yStart =baseImageSize- (y+objectSize)

    padding = tf.convert_to_tensor([[x, xEnd], [yStart, y],[0,0]])

    RTensor = tfObjectMatrix[objectId,:,:,0:1]
    GTensor = tfObjectMatrix[objectId,:,:,1:2]
    BTensor = tfObjectMatrix[objectId,:,:,2:3]
    ATensor = tfObjectMatrix[objectId,:,:,3:4]

    paddedR = tf.pad(tensor = RTensor,
        paddings= padding,
        mode='Constant',
        name='padAverageRed',
        constant_values=255)

    ...
    generates padding for every channel
    ...

    finalTensor=tf.concat([paddedR, paddedG, paddedB, paddedA], 2)
    return finalTensor
```

The `tfObjectMatrix` is a list of images which never change.
I did check wether I was able to generate a `tf.gradient` from the `op`, which turned out to work. I am unsure if that is sufficient for backpropagation to work though.

Thanks for you time and effort. Any input at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow ***will*** backpropagate to everything by default. As per your code, everything will receive gradients with a training operation from an optimizer. So to answer your question, backpropagation *will* work.

The only thing to consider, is that you say `tfObjectMatrix` is a list of images that will not change. So you might *not* want it to receive any gradients. Therefore you might want to look into [`tf.stop_gradient()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient) and maybe use it like `OM = tf.stop_gradient( tfObjectMatrix )` and work with that `OM` in your function.

Comment: Thanks, erhm maybe silly question but why wouldn't I want to receive any gradients?

Comment: Well you want the things you *train* to receive gradients, mainly the weights and biases. If you have something that is constant and you want to keep it that way (`tfObjectMatrix`) then why would you want it to receive gradients and be changed?

Comment: The idea is to train the values of ``vector`` i.e. the input of the function. So could I somehow not comput the gradient for the image but for the values of the vector? (I guess somehow with ``tf.stop_gradient()``)

Comment: That will be difficult. `vector[ 0 ]` can't be trained, that's an index, it can't be changed gradually. Same with `vector[ 1 ]` and `vector[ 2 ]`. I don't think `tf.pad` will provide a gradient for padding size. If you want to do this, you will have to come up with a way where `vector`'s elements are used as floats. You should see if `tf.gradients( op, vector[ 1 : ] )` works at all, or if it complains about those not being connected.

Comment: Well, maybe you can design `vector[ 0 ]` in a way where it's a kind of weight for all the images, enforce a sum of 1 on it, and linearly combine all images based on it. That will coalesce to one of the images if that's what you want. Don't have an idea on top of my head for the padding learning. The problem there is that it will also change the size of the tensor, which is not usually possible once training has started.

Comment: The entire size will be constant of the padding. i.e. the padding pads always to a matrix of sice 800x800x3. However how many of those 800 "pads" are positioned to the left or right will  change with training. Could I use a convolution to fake the padding?

Comment: Ok if it's fixed size then it should be possible. So basically you have a ***800 x 800 x 3*** filled with 255 and you're positioning the image over that at a certain location by ***x*** and ***y***. You have to make the position derivable, continuous, so have to define somehow what happens if ***x = 1.61123*** for example. That will make it trainable. Not sure if you can structure it as a convolution.